# Why there isn't any SQL Server services in SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have not connecting to SQL Server Management Studio. It shows me an error message like in 2nd picture. So, I could not connect to my local SQL Server 2012. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have no entries in your SQL Server Configuration Manager, then you don't have any SQL Server **database engine** installed. Did you install *only* the Management Studio? That's **only** the management GUI - but **NOT** the actual **database core** - the engine. No engine - no database server to connect to ....

Comment: i have uninstalled it . now when i am going to install it i am fetching a problem like System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for userSettings/Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.what should i do now?

Comment: How do i solve the problem   ??? Should i give windows in my system ??

Answer (score 3):

You just installed the management studio. You need to install SQl server. Here you need to install Sql Server and then Sql management studio.

Answer (score 2):

Try `.` instead of `Hello` and see if that connects. If not, then you will have to install a new db instance because you don't have one.

Comment: i have uninstalled it . now when i am going to install it i am fetching a problem like System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for userSettings/Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.what should i do now?

Answer (score 2):

Running the Repair Wizard from the SQL Server Installation Center has solved several of my connection issues when I've received errors connecting to localhost.

Choose Maintenance from the menu on the left, then choose Repair:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Two item have to be installed**

1. SQL Server 2012 Management Studio Express
2. SQL Server 2012 Express

I had only installed only item 1, for this reason i am not getting any database in windows
 authentication mode.

After then by the help of  @marc_s, @CoOl and @Gin Uchiha i have solved my problem
by installing item 2.

And Thanks everyone for responding my question.